# Use Expression Design drawing in WPF (XAML)

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, drawing, expression-blend

I've got some artwork (an image) in expression design that I would like to use in WPF as an `Image`. The reason for this is that its part of a set of icons that will be used in an area of my application where the user can zoom in, and I want it to scale.

My image has a Gaussian Blur effect, and I cannot figure out how to convert it to my `DrawingImage`. When I try to export from expression design, even tho from the warnings it tells me it can export the gaussian blur, it wont. It exports this part of the drawing as a PNG image.

Heres what I've got so far:

When I copy paste the XAML from Expression Design to Expression Blend, I get the following XAML

```
    <Path Stretch="Fill" Fill="#B3000000" Data="F1 M 116.013,62.3682C 140.838,63.5389 160.541,73.4323 160.02,84.4657C 159.5,95.4992 138.954,103.494 114.128,102.324C 89.3031,101.153 69.6001,91.2596 70.1204,80.2262C 70.6407,69.1927 91.1874,61.1974 116.013,62.3682 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40.184" Margin="70.11,62.254,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89.92">
        <Path.Effect>
            <BlurEffect Radius="1.88976"/>
        </Path.Effect>
    </Path>
    <Ellipse Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="83.25" Margin="88.042,19.708,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83.25">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="0.675" RadiusY="0.675" Center="0.660714,0.339286" GradientOrigin="0.660714,0.339286">
                <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <TransformGroup/>
                </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFBC0D0D" Offset="1"/>
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
```

Which I converted to :

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="redSphere">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>  
            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#B3000000" Geometry="F1 M 48.6792,44.0348C 73.5045,45.2056 93.2075,55.099 92.6872,66.1324C 92.1668,77.1658 71.6202,85.1612 46.795,83.9904C 21.9698,82.8197 2.26675,72.9263 2.78708,61.8928C 3.3074,50.8594 23.854,42.8641 48.6792,44.0348 Z "/>
                <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M 62.3333,1.37501C 85.3222,1.37501 103.958,20.0112 103.958,43C 103.958,65.9889 85.3222,84.625 62.3333,84.625C 39.3445,84.625 20.7083,65.9889 20.7083,43C 20.7083,20.0112 39.3445,1.37501 62.3333,1.37501 Z ">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                        <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="0.675" RadiusY="0.675" Center="0.660714,0.339286" GradientOrigin="0.660714,0.339286">
                            <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFBC0D0D" Offset="1"/>
                            </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                <TransformGroup/>
                            </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        </RadialGradientBrush>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingGroup.Children>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

My problem is that now I cant figure out where to put my `BlurEffect`.